# Ionic 3 Ionic command not found in macos

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am facing issue with ionic 3. I downgrade to ionic 3 from 4. And now its showing error of ionic command not found. I try with stackovrflows answers but nothing is working.

Node -v is working only its 8.11.3

I am installing ionic@4.2.1 & cordova 8.0.0 Its installing but commands of ionic isnt working

Comment: restart your machine and reinstall ionic.

Comment: Have you installed ionic as global ?
npm install -g ionic